# Derserializing Json Error : Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize the Json object and it is throwing me the error  Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.

The error is surely  the new piece below as before adding , it was de-serializing correctly. I think it could be StressTestResults which has key value pair values and probably not an array.

New Json added that led to the error above

```
{  
  "StressTestAnalysis":{  
    "StressTestResults": {  
      "curlevel":0,
      "decrease":0,
      "increase":0
    },
    "StressTestGraphData": {
      "yaxis": [ 
        1000000, 
        1500000, 
        2000000, 
        2500000, 
        3000000, 
        14000000 
      ],
      "data": [
        20.00,
        18.18,
        16.53,
        15.03,
        13.66,
        12.42,
        11.29,
        10.26,
        1.68
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

Complete Json

```
{  
  "NpvResults":{  
    "CommIns":[  
      [  
        -4137.0277805691812,
        82.740555611385162,
        1,
        -4054.2872249578099
      ],
      [  
        -4137.0277805691812,
        82.740555611385162,
        2,
        -4054.2872249578099
      ],
      [  
        -4137.0277805691812,
        82.740555611385162,
        3,
        -4054.2872249578099
      ],
      [  
        -4137.0277805691812,
        82.740555611385162,
        4,
        -4054.2872249578099
      ],
      [  
        -4137.0277805691812,
        82.740555611385162,
        5,
        -4054.2872249578099
      ]
    ],
    "CaptiveIns":[  
      [  
        -4221.4569189482418,
        84.429138378963501,
        22.710059979002764,
        -0.019802950859533291,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        -4114.337523541084
      ],
      [  
        -4221.4569189482418,
        84.429138378963501,
        22.752243205547771,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        2,
        -4114.275537363681
      ],
      [  
        -4221.4569189482418,
        84.429138378963501,
        22.749463056422599,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        3,
        -4114.2783175128006
      ],
      [  
        -4221.4569189482418,
        84.429138378963501,
        22.829863952642476,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        4,
        -4114.1979166165802
      ],
      [  
        -4221.4569189482418,
        84.429138378963501,
        22.813678007288622,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        5,
        -4114.2141025619358
      ],
      [  
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        6,
        0
      ]
    ],
    "SelfIns":[  
      [  
        -18.283680484373004,
        0.36567360968745993,
        1,
        -17.918006874685538
      ],
      [  
        -17.950738378065587,
        0.35901476756131162,
        2,
        -17.59172361050425
      ],
      [  
        -17.528414768410823,
        0.35056829536821654,
        3,
        -17.177846473042624
      ],
      [  
        -17.199888318302875,
        0.343997766366058,
        4,
        -16.855890551936845
      ],
      [  
        -16.962838081589766,
        0.33925676163179552,
        5,
        -16.623581319957964
      ]
    ],
    "GraphData":[  
      [  
        -20271.436124789201,
        -20271.436124789201,
        -20271.436124789201,
        -20271.436124789201,
        -20271.436124789201
      ],
      [  
        -20575.839967122232,
        -20573.231848189709,
        -20571.270058283782,
        -20569.376102934919,
        -20567.025718278568
      ],
      [  
        -149.31279568973736,
        -116.11250599884572,
        -85.587513928638344,
        -55.97322678189083,
        -26.126318881224275
      ]
    ],
    "LowestCost":[  
      {  
        "options":"CommIns",
        "prob":0
      },
      {  
        "options":"CaptiveIns",
        "prob":1
      },
      {  
        "options":"SelfIns",
        "prob":0
      }
    ]
  },
  "EvaResults":{  
    "CaptiveView":[  
      [  
        1,
        1004.6356155327186,
        0.019999999999999664,
        50231.780776636006
      ],
      [  
        2,
        1024.6444682949152,
        1004.6556155327187,
        1.0199087932436166
      ],
      [  
        3,
        1045.3665533832836,
        2029.3000838276355,
        0.51513987811914741
      ],
      [  
        4,
        1066.2458049620784,
        3074.6666372109171,
        0.34678575400775757
      ],
      [  
        5,
        1087.6618426753635,
        4140.9124421729957,
        0.26266321517513735
      ]
    ],
    "ParentView":[  
      [  
        1,
        -0.00040000000000000734,
        7500,
        -2000,
        35000,
        40499.999600000519,
        0.019999999999999664,
        2024999.9800000158
      ],
      [  
        2,
        -20.093112310654377,
        7650,
        -2060,
        35000,
        40569.906887689343,
        1004.6556155327187,
        40.382410074732441
      ],
      [  
        3,
        -40.586001676552755,
        7803,
        -2121.1999999999698,
        35000,
        40641.213998323416,
        2029.3000838276355,
        20.027338095426597
      ],
      [  
        4,
        -61.493332744218421,
        7959.0599999998312,
        -2183.6240000000166,
        35000,
        40713.94266725576,
        3074.6666372109171,
        13.241799735750419
      ],
      [  
        5,
        -82.81824884345987,
        8118.241200000044,
        -2247.2964800000163,
        35000,
        40788.126471156589,
        4140.9124421729957,
        9.8500647047036747
      ]
    ],
    "GraphData":[  
      [  
        49809.117488777483,
        50104.699097064135,
        50235.788311093122,
        50362.666684675249,
        50684.163143253129
      ],
      [  
        2025082.8666373945,
        2025083.3307724716,
        2025083.4888383881,
        2025083.6416729619,
        2025084.0321642612
      ]
    ],
    "LowestCost":[  
      {  
        "options":"CaptiveView",
        "prob":1
      },
      {  
        "options":"ParentView",
        "prob":0
      }
    ]
  },
  "EndingSurplusResults":{  
    "EndingSurplusData": {  
      "perc25":6583.7612487804181,
      "perc50":7533.9888417518869,
      "mean":7568.2880884950882,
      "perc75":8491.6674708256032,
      "perc90":9289.8510640642089,
      "perc95":9610.0343551595361
    },
    "GraphData": [  
      8576.4652724267216,
      9410.545525237445,
      9571.0108458564246,
      10038.966929461712,
      9405.1536272893627,
      10079.743965285403,
      8393.2949227139325,
      8908.5518442208522,
      9293.0264829383468,
      9722.8583794184997,
      9141.0634609955559,
      8364.1029286600969,
      8502.6875425273283,
      8976.167984801772,
      7877.4787333027598,
      8952.7424983933197,
      9201.9696148434487,
      8847.4973060152206,
      9747.7562848962589,
      8962.9037815079791,
      9022.1384539308201,
      5681.1573013298594
    ]
  },
  "FinancialStatements":{  
    "IncomeStatement":[  
      [  
        1,
        4178.1932500000103,
        85.269249999998678,
        4263.4624999999414,
        18.465612134335959,
        50.173097169011001,
        170.53849999999736,
        3000,
        1024.2852906966514,
        0.85309250000000236,
        -4642.3097170227602,
        1025.138383196653,
        -3617.171333826107,
        20.502767663933046,
        -72.343426676522142,
        1004.6356155327186,
        1004.6356155327186,
        -92.84619434045527,
        0.016099287680693068,
        0.74365342723195738,
        0.75975271491266771
      ],
      [  
        2,
        4261.7571149999503,
        86.974635000000731,
        4348.7317499999263,
        18.491944231444947,
        51.605102225783959,
        173.94927000000146,
        3060,
        1044.6854335427724,
        0.87014635000001883,
        -4826.5589078423809,
        1045.5555798927724,
        -3781.0033279496056,
        20.911111597855385,
        -75.620066558992093,
        1024.6444682949152,
        1024.6444682949152,
        -189.37737249730282,
        0.016118963064858854,
        0.74365342723195738,
        0.75977239029683274
      ],
      [  
        3,
        4346.9922572999239,
        88.714127700000333,
        4435.7063850000332,
        18.418025530043888,
        52.847080670134723,
        177.42825540000067,
        3121.2000000000389,
        1065.8130233998197,
        0.88754127699999308,
        -4893.8329583179911,
        1066.7005646768214,
        -3827.1323936411636,
        21.334011293536406,
        -76.542647872823409,
        1045.3665533832836,
        1045.3665533832836,
        -287.25403166366249,
        0.016066236133476294,
        0.74365342723195738,
        0.75971966336545038
      ],
      [  
        4,
        4433.932102446006,
        90.488410253999461,
        4524.4205127000223,
        18.434282054184305,
        54.284770809664288,
        180.97682050799892,
        3183.6239999999598,
        1087.1006393281507,
        0.90528410254000691,
        -5189.5034432464236,
        1088.0059234306907,
        -4101.4975198157326,
        21.760118468613825,
        -82.029950396314604,
        1066.2458049620784,
        1066.2458049620784,
        -391.04410052859066,
        0.016072567229267684,
        0.74365342723195738,
        0.75972599446124212
      ],
      [  
        5,
        4522.610744494943,
        92.298178459080859,
        4614.9089229540396,
        18.543823690342677,
        55.536620991960014,
        184.59635691816172,
        3247.2964800000173,
        1108.9356413535372,
        0.92338178459078979,
        -5236.1929873248337,
        1109.8590231381279,
        -4126.3339641867033,
        22.197180462762532,
        -82.526679283733927,
        1087.6618426753635,
        1087.6618426753635,
        -495.76796027508777,
        0.016052417484088474,
        0.74365342723195738,
        0.7597058447160624
      ]
    ],
    "CashFlow":[  
      [  
        1,
        4263.4624999999414,
        18.465612134335959,
        3000,
        -72.343426676522142,
        170.53849999999736,
        1146.8018145421861,
        -22.936036290843688,
        0.85309250000000236,
        0.019999999999999664,
        1124.7388707513417,
        0,
        0
      ],
      [  
        2,
        4348.7317499999263,
        18.491944231444947,
        3060,
        -75.620066558992093,
        173.94927000000146,
        1171.9106023275467,
        -23.438212046550877,
        0.87014635000001883,
        0,
        2274.081407382339,
        1124.7388707513417,
        0
      ],
      [  
        3,
        4435.7063850000332,
        18.418025530043888,
        3121.2000000000389,
        -76.542647872823409,
        177.42825540000067,
        1195.20275194278,
        -23.904055038855581,
        0.88754127699999308,
        0,
        2321.5287748119181,
        1149.3425366309982,
        0
      ],
      [  
        4,
        4524.4205127000223,
        18.434282054184305,
        3183.6239999999598,
        -82.029950396314604,
        180.97682050799892,
        1223.4153605341307,
        -24.46830721068261,
        0.90528410254000691,
        0,
        2372.0385756069109,
        1172.1862381809224,
        0
      ],
      [  
        5,
        4614.9089229540396,
        18.543823690342677,
        3247.2964800000173,
        -82.526679283733927,
        184.59635691816172,
        1246.9989416292328,
        -24.939978832584625,
        0.92338178459078979,
        0,
        2422.8346820072279,
        1199.8523374259858,
        0
      ]
    ],
    "BalanceSheet":[  
      [  
        1,
        0.019999999999999664,
        -92.84619434045527,
        -22.936036290843688,
        50.173097169011001,
        1004.6356155327186,
        0.019999999999999664,
        835.63864999998646,
        0,
        0.019999999999999664,
        1004.6556155327187,
        0,
        0,
        1004.6756155327198,
        1054.82871270173,
        1124.7388707513417,
        1101.8228344604984
      ],
      [  
        2,
        0.019999999999999664,
        -189.37737249730282,
        -46.37424833739469,
        101.77819939479492,
        1024.6444682949152,
        0.019999999999999664,
        852.35142299998779,
        1004.6556155327187,
        0,
        2029.3000838276355,
        0,
        0,
        2029.3200838276339,
        2131.0782832224281,
        2274.081407382339,
        2227.7271590449436
      ],
      [  
        3,
        0.019999999999999664,
        -287.25403166366249,
        -70.278303376250193,
        154.62528006492957,
        1045.3665533832836,
        0.019999999999999664,
        869.39845145997833,
        2029.3000838276355,
        0,
        3074.6666372109171,
        0,
        0,
        3074.686637210918,
        3229.2919172758507,
        2321.5287748119181,
        2251.2704714356696
      ],
      [  
        4,
        0.019999999999999664,
        -391.04410052859066,
        -94.746610586932803,
        208.91005087459402,
        1066.2458049620784,
        0.019999999999999664,
        886.78642048919619,
        3074.6666372109171,
        0,
        4140.9124421729957,
        0,
        0,
        4140.9324421729971,
        4349.8224930475881,
        2372.0385756069109,
        2277.3119650199792
      ],
      [  
        5,
        0.019999999999999664,
        -495.76796027508777,
        -119.68658941951738,
        264.44667186655391,
        1087.6618426753635,
        0.019999999999999664,
        904.52214889900233,
        4140.9124421729957,
        0,
        5228.5742848483651,
        0,
        0,
        5228.5942848483655,
        5493.0209567149213,
        2422.8346820072279,
        2303.1680925877076
      ]
    ]
  },
  "StressTestAnalysis":{  
    "StressTestResults": {  
      "curlevel":0,
      "decrease":0,
      "increase":0
    },
    "StressTestGraphData": {
      "yaxis": [ 
        1000000, 
        1500000, 
        2000000, 
        2500000, 
        3000000, 
        14000000 
      ],
      "data": [
        20.00,
        18.18,
        16.53,
        15.03,
        13.66,
        12.42,
        1.68
      ]
    }
  },
  "PackList":[  
    {  
      "tblname":"CommIns",
      "cols":"premPaid;taxDeduction;year;netCostProj",
      "Item":"NpvResults"
    },
    {  
      "tblname":"CaptiveIns",
      "cols":"premPaid;taxDeduction;loanToParent;capContriDistr;dividendDistr;terminalVal;year;netCostProj",
      "Item":"NpvResults"
    },
    {  
      "tblname":"SelfIns",
      "cols":"discountedLossesPaid;discountedTaxDeduction;year;netCostProj",
      "Item":"NpvResults"
    },
    {  
      "tblname":"GraphData",
      "cols":"CommIns;CaptiveIns;SelfIns",
      "Item":"NpvResults"
    },
    {  
      "tblname":"CaptiveView",
      "cols":"year;captiveNetIncome;surplusDeployed;impliedRoi",
      "Item":"EvaResults"
    },
    {  
      "tblname":"ParentView",
      "cols":"year;costOfCapDeployed;costOfRiskArb;incrCost;npvTaxBenefit;outcome;surplusDeployed;impliedRoi",
      "Item":"EvaResults"
    },
    {  
      "tblname":"GraphData",
      "cols":"CaptiveView;ParentView",
      "Item":"EvaResults"
    },
    {  
      "tblname":"IncomeStatement",
      "cols":"year;directPremWritten;cededPremWritten;netPremWritten;lossesLaePaid;chgResIbnr;othrUwExp;gaExp;uwGain;netInvestmentIncome;irsDiscount;preTaxOpIncomeWithIrs;preTaxOpIncomeWithoutIrs;fedIncomeTaxWithIrs;fedIncomeTaxWithoutIrs;netOperatingIncome;netIncome;deferredTaxAssets;lossLaeRatio;expRatio;netCombinedRatio",
      "Item":"FinancialStatements"
    },
    {  
      "tblname":"CashFlow",
      "cols":"year;premCollected;lossLaePaid;gaExpPaid;fedIncomeTaxPaid;othrUwExpPaid;netCashByOpActivities;loanBack;invPurchasedSold;capPaidIn;cashInvEndOfYear;cashInvStartOfYear;dividendsPaid",
      "Item":"FinancialStatements"
    },
    {  
      "tblname":"BalanceSheet",
      "cols":"year;othrAssets;defFedIncTax;loanbackAsset;totLiabilities;retainedEarnings;nonControllingInt;capAdequacyReqd;capital;addnPaidInCap;shareholderEquity;additionallyNeeded;distribute;totShareholderEquity;totLiabilitiesTotShEquity;totCashInvestment;totAssets",
      "Item":"FinancialStatements"
    }
  ]
}
```

Trigger2Output class that maps to the Json

```
 [JsonConverter(typeof(MinifyingJsonConverter))]
    public class StressTestAnaylsis
    {
        public StressTestResults StressTestResults { get; set; }
        public StressTestGraphData StressTestGraphData { get; set; }
    }

  public class StressTestResults
    {
        [JsonMinify]
        public double curlevel { get; set; }
        [JsonMinify]
        public double decrease { get; set; }
        [JsonMinify]
        public double increase { get; set; }
    }

    public class StressTestGraphData
    {
        [JsonMinify]
        public List<int> yaxis { get; set; }
        [JsonMinify]
        public List<double> data { get; set; }
    }
```

Method that deserialises

```
public void Trigger2_Output_Deserialize_JSON_Minified()
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText("Models\\Trigger2OutputMinified.json");

            var o = JObject.Parse(json);
            var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Trigger2Output>(o.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: If you construct the datastructure programatically and serialize it, does it look the same as the data you're trying to deserialize?

Comment: Sorry didnt get your question

Comment: Why do you use MinifyingJsonConverter for StressTestAnaylsis? The corresponding Json does not look compacted/minified at all. Which probably is the cause of your problem. I recall you had already some problem with compacted/minified Json not that long ago. Perhaps it is advisable not to use MinifyingJsonConverter/compacted Json (if possible), as this will save you from these problems you struggle with...

Comment: I have removed that and the error has gone but StressTestAnaylsis is showing null, means its not parsing it correctly. No error though. Is there any problem with the way tjhe key value pair has been defined

Comment: I see you have a name mismatch between the Json object and your class. You named the class `StressTestAnaylsis` instead of `StressTestAnalysis`. Note the typo (l and y are flipped). Since the deserializer didn't find the misspelled `StressTestAnaylsis` in the Json data, it assigned the default value null.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. You have saved my time

Comment: If you look at my first comment, you will notice that i too did not spot the typo in your class name right away, since i copied&pasted it into my comment including the typo...  :)))